# Update after dialog box is closed in android

Tags: android, list, listview, dialog

I have a list which I am displaying in android. If any of the item is clicked a custom dialog box appears. The user then enters some value in its EditView and closes it.

The issue is:
Though I am able the read what user has entered but i also want to update the data that user entered in the dialog box into the item that was clicked.

Please can anyone tell me how to do that?
Is Dialog box the right View to be used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to load your list then you should not have any problem, as long as your are notifying your changes in your `provider`. If you arent using a `CursorLoader` you will need a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to update your `List` (reload it all).
Here is a little help from Android: [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)